# Greek letter in the notation for martingale problem

Tags: greek

This is nothing but just a question about greek letters in the notation of III.1.9 in Jacod and Shirayeav (2003):

[image]

In here, what is the letter [image]? and how can I write in LaTeX?

It would be very appreciated if you let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: It is not a greek letter. Looks like a calligraphic lowercase `s`.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `pdfLaTeX` with the package `calligra`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
$\mbox{{\calligra s}}\,(\mathscr{H},\mu\mid P_H,\nu)(abc)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Like @Bernard said, its calligraphic lowercase s `\mathscr{s}`.

With `TeX Gyre Schola Math` font

`$\mathscr{s}(\mathscr{H}, μ \big|\mathit{P_{H}}, ν)$`

looks like this:

[image: math]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\begin{document}

$\mathscr{s}(\mathscr{H}, μ \big|\mathit{P_{H}}, ν)$

\end{document}
```

Greeks letter can be set also with `$\mu \nu$`.

Comment: I think the last letter is `\nu` instead of `v`.

Comment: `$v  \nu$` [(v and ν)](http://i.imgur.com/MXkvFbH.png)

Comment: Yet, in OP's picture, if you have a close look, i really think it's a `\nu`, but one can choose what he wants ;)